# How to add directory to samba which i want to share

Tags: linux

I have followed steps to install samba on ubuntu from

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-samba-server-on-ubuntu/

But it didn't tell me how can i add a directory e,g

```
/var/www
```

in to share with window users or macusers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample `smb.conf` share section.

This creates a single share named "Utilities" for the folder `/opt/Utils`.  It gives write access to user "username", denies access to user "root", read access to the guest user and everyone else.  Some example options are included that demonstrate file & directory creation masks and filename case handling.

```
# share name
# this is the name of the share shown in Windows share browser and "net view" command
[Utilities]

        # comment shows up in Windows share browser
        comment = Handy-dandy software repository

        # path to share
        path = /opt/Utils

        # share security -- who can access, who can't, who can write
        write list = username
        read only = yes
        directory mask = 0755
        create mask = 0644
        guest ok = Yes
        invalid users = root

        # filename case options, mostly for Win clients
        case sensitive = True
        default case = lower
        preserve case = yes
        short preserve case = yes
```

Comment: There is no [utilities] text written in that file

Comment: this is just an example.  change `[Utilities]` to whatever you want your share name to be, and change `path = ` to the folder you want to share, and change the security & case options to whatever you need.

Comment: that worked perfectly buddy